# Android IPC by reference

Tags: android, ipc

I'm working with Android framework for custom ROM.
For a reason I need to send an Object to another application by reference, not by cloning the data. don't want AIDL or intent because they need to copy the data through Parcelable or Json.

Like this:

```
App1
void func1(TextView t)
{
   App2.func2(t);
}

App2
void func2(TextView t)
{
   String s=t.toString();
}
```

guess sending a reference is possible because I heard there is no concept of process in JVM, so no boundary of processes. Is it possible? if not, can it be done under the JNI with C++ shared memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has it's own virtual machine called Dalvik and on the contrary of JVM, Dalvik runs different applications in different instances of DalvikVM (processes). Thus, in Android there are several IPC mechanisms (Binder is one of them).

In your case, you need to use Ashmem. It's a kind of shared memory but specially for Android. I have only theoretical knowledge in this sphere, never tried it for my own.

[Here](http://www.androidenea.com/2010/03/share-memory-using-ashmem-and-binder-in.html) is an article how to create shared memory region.

Comment: [MemoryFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MemoryFile.html) is an ashmem wrapper, and using reflection you can get a file descriptor that you can pass between processes.

Comment: To send file descriptor you can use Binder.

Comment: Thanks, but I newly heard that AIDL uses memory file / shared memory internally, so now no need to bother with shared memory for performance.

Comment: Maybe in the new versions, but as for Gingerbread, Binder does not use shared memory. It simply copies data from one process to another.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have the same reference, the only way is to copy the object via various IPC mechanics, but reference will be different as those are 2 separate process that can't share the memory.